# Order of execution of on-click, ng-class & $digest cycles

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

I've got a ui-view that swaps between 3 different templates. One of the requirements though, is that the templates slide in and out from the left or the right side depending on what link is clicked within each template.

Now the problem that I'm facing, is something along the following lines:

```
<div ui-view class='list' ng-class="{'slide-left':myCon.direction=='left','slide-right:myCon.direction=='right'}">
    <a ng-click="myCon.setDirectionAndGoToState('right')">slide Right</a>
    <a ng-click="myCon.setDirectionAndGoToState('left')">slide Left</a>
</div>
```

What I'm seeing in the DOM through Chrome's developer tools, is that when the  click happens on the "slide Right" link, both the ui-view elements (both the leaving and the newly generate entering ones) get the correct `.slide-right` classes.
And then the leaving ui-view element disappears, and the active ui-view element has the class of `.slide-right`.
Now if I were to then click the "Slide Left" link, then the leaving ui-view has the `.slide-left` class applied, but the newly generated entering ui-view still has the `.slide-right` class applied... Presumably from when it was duplicated... Which therefore implies that the duplication from the `$state.go` executed in the function triggered by the ng-click event, is actually happening before the ng-class. Or at least that's the implication that I'm getting....

Does anybody have any idea if that's what is actually going on... If it is, is there a way for me to change the order so that the ng-class is being evaluated after the new direction is set within the controller, and for the $state.go to only perform its duplication *after*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include the content of your `setDirectionAndGoToState()` function, but if all you want to do is control the order of operations, it's fairly simple to do. Remember that Javascript is single-threaded. The AngularJS "digest" mechanism runs at the very end of each event processing cycle, and that's where things like your ng-class expression will be evaluated. If things like a `$state.go(...)` are executing too early for you, just move them to the "next tick". This is the usual trick:

```
$scope.setDirectionAndGoToState = function(direction) {
    $scope.direction = direction;
    $timeout(function() {
        $state.go('newstate');
    }, 0);
};
```

Calling timeout in this way will defer the execution of the code inside until the "next tick" - after the digest cycle has run. This will let the classes get applied before transitioning to the new state. You can obviously mix and match uses of this mechanism (or even nesting them) to get precise control over the ordering.

Just be aware that while this is fine for occasional events like state transitions, it does introduce a slight delay - no callback is ever ZERO milliseconds. I wouldn't recommend using this for something like a window-resize event handler - there are other tricks for those cases.